# Hidden embed src still takes up space

Tags: audio, embed, hidden

I have the following embedded code:

```
<embed src="audio/tileSelect.wav" autostart="false" width="1" height="1" hidden="true" id="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
<embed src="audio/tileRemove.wav" autostart="false" width="1" height="1" hidden="true" id="sound2" enablejavascript="true">
```

Though these are hidden (and I don't see them), they still take up space. How can I remove the extra space they use?

I've tried putting it in a div with `display: none;`, but that stopped my audio from working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hmm got a solution (though not very pretty):

```
.au {
    position: relative; 
    top: -50px; 
    left: -50px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Put it in a div and give it these proportions

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not working for me, there is still a gap on the screen when using IE7-9.  I know this is an old post and browsers have changed since this answer was given.  Take this code below and save it as `audio.html` and run it in IE7-10 and the latest versions of Chrome, Safari, and FireFox.  You will see that using the style in the accepted answer still displays a gap on the screen with IE7-9.  The method I am using does not.

Also, I am using the **[HTML5 `<audio>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)** when available and then falling back to the **[`<embed>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp)** when needed.  I haven't done much research but this is what **[w3schools currently recommends](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp)** and I've tested all major browsers and versions so as of May 13, 2014 it seems to be working great for me.

Hope this helps.

(audio may take a second to start playing, its coming from archive.org)

```
<div style="background-color:lightgray; height:100px; width:300px; padding:5px;">
    This is the solution I am using so that the embed tag doesn't take up any room...<br>
    Audio is embedded below this block.  You will see no gap in any browser.
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;">
    <audio autoplay>
        <source src="https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <embed width="1" height="1" hidden="true" src="https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3">
    </audio>
</div>
<div style="background-color:gray; height:20px; width:300px; padding:5px;">
    Audio is embedded above this block
</div>

<div style="background-color:aqua; height:100px; width:300px; padding:5px; margin-top:30px;">
    Using a div with "position: relative; top: -50px; left: -50px; overflow: hidden;" still gives a gap...<br>
    Audio is embedded below this block.  You will see a gap in IE7-9.
</div>
<div style="position: relative; top: -50px; left: -50px; overflow: hidden;">
    <audio autoplay>
        <source src="https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <embed width="1" height="1" hidden="true" src="https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3">
    </audio>
</div>
<div style="background-color:green; height:20px; width:300px; padding:5px;">
    Audio is embedded above this block
</div>
```